# Multiple Doctrine query to pull a specific record using sfGuard plugin

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am trying to pull a specific set of records from a table called Faculty, by retrieving a specific parameter from another table. I am getting the id from the sfGuard User, then retrieving the record from the ID. From there I would like to pull out the department title from that table and display only records from Faculty with that department title.

This is what I have in my actions.class:

```
$userId = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
$userRecord = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from ('sfGuardUser s')
        ->where("s.id = '$userId'")
        ->limit('1')
        ->execute();
$userDept = $userRecord['department_title'];        
$this->facultyAdminFind = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from ("Faculty a")
        ->where("a.notables LIKE ?", "%$userDept%")
        ->execute();
```

After doing some troubleshooting, I know I am pulling the correct ID and the correct record from sfGuardUser table. I just can't seem to pull the department title from the sfGuardUser record. 
The loop is coming up with nothing.

If I change $userDept = $userRecord['department_title']; to $userDept = "Engineering";

**Update to questions below:**

I am getting the userID, then asking for the department_title of that ID. I can get the id using getGuardUser(), but not 'department_title' right? If so, what would that syntax look like?

I am sure there is a department title and there are no misspellings. I actually worked from this backwrds to verify all variables that were being pulled

First I did this:

```
$this->facultyAdminFind = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from ('sfGuardUser s')
        ->where("s.id = '$userId'")
        ->limit('1')
        ->execute();
```

which returned the correct record in the loop and I was able to use $item['department_title"] in the template to call the department title correctly. So I know I am getting the correct userID and calling the correct record into $userRecord.

Also, inside Faculty::notables there are strings with Engineering. That is why I did this:

```
$userDept = "Engineering";
```

And I was able to get a result of all records with Engineering in notables.

**This is what I found that works:**

Per ProdigitalSon I was able to look at the model and figure out how to pull the dept title from the user table. This is working.

```
$userId = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getDepartmentTitle();
    $this->facultyAdminFind = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from ("Faculty a")
            ->where("a.notables LIKE ?", "%$userId%")
            ->execute();
```

**UPDATE:**

I learned you should not modify the sfGuard schema because if you update the plugin, you would lose the specialized schema. I have added a new class in the main schema, and have a working association between sf_guard_user and department_title.

The issue is I am back to square one with trying to get the department_title from the array.
Here is the added schema:

```
MyUserProfile:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    sf_guard_user_id: { type:integer }
    department_title: { type: string(255) }
    # ... other column definitions
  relations:
    User:
     class: sfGuardUser
     foreignType: one
     foreignAlias: Profile
     local: sf_guard_user_id
     onDelete: CASCADE
```

And this is the query that should work (in my head).

```
//pulls department limited records for faculty admin
    $userId = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
    $usergetDept = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('MyUserProfile d')
            ->where("d.sf_guard_user_id = '$userId'")
            ->execute();

    $userDept = $usergetDept['department_title'];
    $this->facultyAdminFind = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from ("Faculty a")
            ->where("a.notables LIKE ?", "%$userDept%")
            ->execute();
```

This is pulling every record, not just the ones with the department_title. Could I do this easier with a multiple join maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs thing that stands out is why are you querying for the user when you already have the user. You dont need to query `sfGuardUser` again you already have that record from calling `myUser::getGuardUser()`.

So the next thing is are you sure the record youre working with has a `department_title` property set? Are you sure you didnt mispell the column name either in the schema or in the snippet code? And are us sure that the value in the `sfGuardUser::department_title` youre working with does in fact match some records in `Faculty::notables`?

Comment: Using your suggestion about already having the user made me look into the model to see what was derived from the schema. I found the model built the get function from the schema. It was getDepartmentTitle(). I have posted my correct code in the question.

Comment: Im glad you got it fixed but if the getter was `getDepartmentTitle` that implies the column name is `department_title` in which case `$user['department_title'] should work, unless you have array access turned off, which im not even sure if you can do... i think its only autogenerated accessor methods you can turn on/off

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue of getting the department_title from the MyUserProfile class

After adding the relation to the schema, you can call the record like this:

```
    $getProfile = $this->getUser()->getProfile();

    $userDept = $getProfile['department_title'];
    $this->facultyAdminFind = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from ("Faculty a")
            ->where("a.notables LIKE ?", "%$userDept%")
            ->execute();
```